# but my Navbar items is not working properly. Whenever I tried to click on any navbar's item it is not displaying me the result

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

export class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    let design = {
      textDecoration: 'none',
      paddingLeft: '30px',
      paddingright: '30px',

    };

    return (
      <div>
        <nav className='navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light '>
          <div className='container-fluid'>
            <NavLink className='navbar-brand' to='/'>
              News24*7
            </NavLink>
            <button
              className='navbar-toggler'
              type='button'
              data-bs-toggle='collapse'
              data-bs-target='#navbarSupportedContent'
              aria-controls='navbarSupportedContent'
              aria-expanded='false'
              aria-label='Toggle navigation'
            >
              <span className='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
            </button>
            <div
              className='collapse navbar-collapse'
              id='navbarSupportedContent'
            >
              <ul className='navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0'>
                <li className='nav-item'>
                  <NavLink className='nav-NavLink' aria-current='page' to='/'>
                    Home
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className='nav-item' style={design}>
                  <NavLink className='nav-NavLink' to='/about'>
                    About
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className='nav-item' style={design}>
                  <NavLink className='nav-NavLink' to='/business'>
                    Business
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className='nav-item' style={design}>
                  <NavLink className='nav-NavLink' to='/entertainment'>
                    Entertainment
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className='nav-item' style={design}>
                  <NavLink className='nav-NavLink' to='/health'>
                    Health
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className='nav-item' style={design}>
                  <NavLink className='nav-NavLink' to='/science'>
                    Science
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className='nav-item' style={design}>
                  <NavLink className='nav-NavLink' to='/sports'>
                    Sports
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className='nav-item' style={design}>
                  <NavLink className='nav-NavLink' to='/technology'>
                    Technology
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className='nav-item' style={design}>
                  <NavLink className='nav-NavLink' to='/contact'>
                    Contact Us
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Here I am creating a news app where I am passing category as a props to my navbar. but my  Navbar items is not working properly. Whenever I tried to click on any navbar's item it is not displaying me the result.
For example  when I click on any navbar item, it is not displaying me the result and If I reload my page then it works properly . I tried to use exact, end  before path but it didn't workout.

Comment: A code snippet would be great

Comment: How did you create your routes? Show the code